# When creating a simple gui in swift and simulating it, i get a blank screen until i rotate then i see the gui. Why would this happen?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I am new to creating applications in xcode (normally a windows girl).  Trying to create a basic GUI that only has a input line, title and some text.  When trying to simulate it, I get a white screen. If I rotate the screen everthing shows up but by default its blank.  I tethered the screen but still seems to have a problem.  any ideas?  I found this has to be due to my resolution or simulator resolution.  When I create a blank storyboard and play it as a single application I don't see anything till I rotate and I see the battery life and time.  Where is the setting to update this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample code showing off the issue.  Can you reduce your app to a small reproduction case that you could share here?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I can give the steps since there isn't much coding involved since this happens even with a blank canvas.  I've been playing around with the following tutorial listed here.  The issue is even withwith starting a single application it still shows at simulation time no time or battery power.  It only shows up after I rotate.  But I tried creating the steps in the link below and still after anchoring doesn't show up till i rotate.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me when I have an issue with Auto Layout. My objects in Storyboard were not being pinned down right, causing the objects to be rendered off-screen when in portrait.

I would look at your constraints in Storyboard. You can pin down where objects are placed. If you do not, iOS will decide, and the results are not necessarily what you want.

This is the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html) on setting layout constraints to start with.

For a simple app, I would place my objects where I want them. Then I would Control-drag each element to the left side of the screen and set Leading, and then Control-drag each element to the top of the screen to set Top. You will be given these options when the mouse cursor has hit the edge of the depicted iOS device screen. This which gives you basic x,y constraints. For labels and text fields it is optional, but you might want to set up a height and width too.

Comment: Thanks Russell.  I did try that with my gui (using apples web page "Start developing ios apps).  The funny thing is when I create a new single application and don't put anything on the screen but simulate it, I don't even see the battery life on the top till I rotate and then its off the screen.  Is that still due to layout?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to scale down my windows in order to see it.  I figured it had to be something to do with the resolution and the default settings for the simulation.  :) For those of you who get stuck like me after you simulate go to window -> Scale -> and drop to 50%.  By default it was set to 100% and with the out of the box macbook air system it was cut off.  Thanks for those you responded.  Time to finish my tutorial and write my app!